# ¿Como manejar excepciones en ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy implementando el manejo de excepciones en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC 5, y he optado por usar HandleErrorAttribute, aquí el código que implemente

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(DbUpdateException), View = "Error")]
public class CompaniaController : Controller
{
    private CompaniaRepository companiaRepository = null;

    public CompaniaController()
    {
        this.companiaRepository = new CompaniaRepository(new InventarioContext());
    }      

    public ActionResult Listar()
    {
        var companias = companiaRepository.Listar().ToList();
        List<Moneda> monedas = monedaRepository.Listar().ToList();

        ViewBag.Monedas = new SelectList(monedas, "MonedaID", "Descripcion");

        return View( "Listar", companias);
    }
}
```

También agrego la configuración del `web.config`

```
<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
```

Ejecutando la aplicación en modo debug veo que primeramente se cae, y luego de darle F5 recién sale la vista con el mensaje de error. ¿A que se debo aquello?, o que parte me falta configurar para que la vista de error sea la que aparezca y no se caiga la aplicación

Agradezco su tiempo.

Comment: Estaría bien que incluyeras algún detalle sobre los errores, captura de pantalla, ...

Comment: A que llamas "primeramente se cae" ? es logico que primero debe darse el exception y despues es atrapado por el atributo para redireccionar a la vista de error, es corecto que sea de esta forma.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini , cuando menciono "primeramente se cae" quice decir que la `aplicación` se detiene en una de las `líneas` del controlador(donde se presenta el error), luego de darle F5 **recien me sale la vista** que esta configurada para el error (Views/Shared/Error.cshtml), yo pense que cuando se genera un excepción se dirigía directamente a la vista de error, osea sin que se tenga que presionar F5 para que recien aparezca la vista de error, ¿o es que estoy entendiendo mal la forma de implementar excepciones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**>>cuando menciono "primeramente se cae" quice decir que la aplicación se detiene en una de las líneas del controlador(donde se presenta el error), luego de darle F5 recien me sale la vista que esta configurada para el error**

Pero ese efecto se presenta porque estas depurando con el VS, este primero detiene el código para que puedas inspeccionar el problema y analizar el detalle.

Cuando confirmas que quieres continuar (presionando F5) es que prosigue con la próxima operacion, o sea, ejecuta la acción del atributo para redireccionar la la view del error.

Cuando publiques la aplicacion en el IIS no se producirá ese efecto, sino que sera continuo y solo veras la view del mensaje.

---

Sino quieres que se detenga la ejecucion ante un error podrías desmarcando el control de `Exceptions`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]